# Defining Python function with input

Tags: python, postgresql, function

I have Postgres table called Records with several appIds. I am writing a function to pull out the data for one `AppId` (ABC0123) and want to store this result in dataframe `df`. 
I have created a variable AppId1 to store my AppId(ABC0123) and passed it to the query.
The script got executed, but it did not create the dataframe.

```
def fun(AppId):
    AppId1=pd.read_sql_query(""" select "AppId" from "Records" where "AppId"='%s'""" %AppId,con=engine )
    query = """" SELECT AppId from "Records" where AppId='%s' """ % AppId1
    df=pd.read_sql_query(query,con=engine)
    return fun

fun('ABC0123')
```

Comment: `return fun` ??..Why?...You should be returning `df` not your function reference?..`return df`

Comment: Your definition of `query` starts with four double quotes. That means the fourth quote is part of the string data, so the string contains `" SELECT AppId from "Records" where AppId='%s' `. Is that a typo in question entry, or a code bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Change % AppId1 to % AppId only.
- return df

```
def fun(AppId):
    AppId1=pd.read_sql_query(""" select 'AppId' from 'Records' where 'AppId'='%s'""" %AppId,con=engine )
    query = """ SELECT 'AppId' from 'Records' where AppId='%s' """ %AppId
    df=pd.read_sql_query(query,con=engine)
    return df
```

Comment: Thank you.. I changed it to %AppId and return df - I could print the appId values but the variable df is not created.

Comment: @Prasad - Please check the edited code once again and let me know.